# Lost SSH access after setting up OpenVPN (Possible issue using non default SSH port)

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I was setting up OpenVPN using this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04.

I wasn't having luck in getting the keys off the host machine and I lost my original SSH connection while troubleshooting. When I set up the server a few years ago I had changed the default SSH port to [redacted]. I now realzie that I needed to configure that port somewhere before enabling UFW.

Is there anyway to gain access to my server again? I'd like to avoid resorting to the nuclear option if possible.

Thanks for reading!
-TheBigL

Comment: If there is no firewall other than UFW, you can try every possible port. If you have set up an SSH key that does not require a password, you can automize this too.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot. Hopefully there's an open port. Don't have a key :(

Comment: Why was it necessary to hide the port you are using? It could have been a clue.